# Cant get SQL results to write to file Java

Tags: java, sql

The title says it all. This is my ResultSet code:

```
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        int ID  = rs.getInt("ID");
        String Name = rs.getString("Name");
        String CountryCode = rs.getString("CountryCode");
        String District = rs.getString("District");
        int Population = rs.getInt("Population");

        //Display values
        try {
            writeToFile(ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my writeToFile method:

```
public void writeToFile(int id, String name, String countryCode, String district, int population) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\horry\\Desktop\\results.txt");
    fw.write(id + " " + name + " " + countryCode + " " + district + " " + population + "\n");
    try {
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ive tried the usual flush and close method but something is missing. Should the filewriter be declared elsewgere?

Comment: No exceptions. One line gets written but with an incorrect ID. Do you know a better method?

Comment: Can you use the debugger (or logging) to see if the name, countryCode, etc. variables are being populated (or write a test case that passes in hard coded values for these parameters)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open file with append option

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\horry\\Desktop\\results.txt", true);
```

To add new line in any platform (e.g. linux ) use general line seperator as below

```
fw.write(id + " " + name + " " + countryCode + " " + district + " " + population + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: This worked in the sense that my file is now filled. Any thoughts on creating new lines for each query?

Comment: updated with new line for each query, please accept the answer if it works

Answer (score -1):

You are opening a new FileWriter for each iteration of your ResultSet. By default a FileWriter writes at the beginning of the file. So you are continously overwritting what you have written in the file at the previous iteration.

Furthermore, I would advice to not create a new FileWriter at each iteration. I would open a FileWriter just one time and use the same one for all the ietrations.

Then, use a BufferedWriter instead of a pure FileWriter. It will be much faster.

Also, close the writer in a finally block, not within the try. Since Java 7, you can even use try-with-resources.

Finally, use `br.newLine();` to write a new line instead of managing the "\n" yourself.

Please check the code below

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\horry\\Desktop\\results.txt");
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        int id  = rs.getInt("ID");
        String name = rs.getString("Name");
        String countryCode = rs.getString("CountryCode");
        String district = rs.getString("District");
        int population = rs.getInt("Population");
        bw.write(id + " " + name + " " + countryCode + " " + district + " " + population);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```